# Chinese characters in Sitefinity MVC Partial view are not rendered properly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

In the main content, the chinese characters are displayed correctly.

However when I render a partial using `@Html.Action`, it is rendered like this:

[image]

I've tried using the same characters in the main body, and it displays correctly.

[image: How it is rendered]

What could be the issue?

Comment: How does it actually 'render' in the browser? Characters may look weird in the HTML code (because of UTF-8 or other encodings) but may actually display as desired on the final result

Comment: It doesn't render correctly, updated it with the picture..

Comment: can you show the code that renders the text inside the <span>

Comment: @VeselinVasilev https://gist.github.com/weirdyang/bdc976467605c3fea6380d09a883c439

Comment: @Lee do you have <meta charset="utf-8" /> in your layout (page template) file?

Comment: yes. <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a codepage issue.

You need to save the view file with Unicode (UTF with signature) encoding.

See what happens when I tried to save the view with some of the characters from your view:

[image: Save with encoding dialog]

Click Save with other encoding and then select Unicode:

[image]

Comment: I just moved the code into the main page instead of the partial and it worked.

Comment: probably because the codepage of the main page (view) has been saved with the correct encoding.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try it and report back